# Using the Multipeer Connectivity framework on a cross platform app

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, lan

I want to use [Apple's Multipeer Connectivity framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html) in an upcoming app. My problem is that this app should also be available for Android, and iOS users should be able to use it communicate with Android users. The Multipeer Connectivity framework does not appear to be cross platform, and I have been unable to find any implementations of it for Android.

It seems that Android has a package for [creating P2P Wi-Fi connections](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html), a package for [Near Field Communication](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html), and a package for [Bluetooth Low Energy communication](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html). What's missing is something like Multipeer Connectivity that abstracts these services into a single API. So I don't see any kind of a platform independent alternative.

**So what should I do? What is the normal way for nearby devices to communicate across platforms?**

Comment: Please suggest what have you done for your above problem, stuck in the same loophole